# Importance of metrization theorem?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I wonder if there is a case metrization theorems(such as Nagata-Smirnov, Bing, Urysohn) pave a way to do a theory.

What would be a nice application of metrization theorems?

Comment: Metrization theorems mean you can apply the theory of metric spaces to your topological space. Since metric spaces are so nice, this is convenient.

Comment: If you want to prove that a space is metrizable you can use these theorems.  It will usually be much easier to show the space is regular and second countable, for instance, than to define a metric and show the original and metric topologies coincide.

Comment: If you are working with infinite dimensional topological vector spaces, then metrization theorems becomes a very powerful tool to get a translation invariant metric.

Comment: @tessellation I have heard that metrization theorems are very useful in differential geometry and etc (but this is just what I heard, I haven't seen any.)Would you please give me an example specifically in which infinite dimensional topological space  the metrization theorems become useful?

Comment: Rudin's functional analysis book. Theorem 1.24 (which is a version of Urysohn's metrization theorem). Therem 1.27 (F-space is a topological vector space with a translation invariant metric). Theorem 1.32 (this theorem shows the advantage of having a metric).